# Querying large SQLite DB causes UI freezing even if performed in another thread

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading, sqlite

My app comes pre-shipped with three databases. One is large with 293,092 rows containing mostly long sentences. My problem is whenever I query (rawQuery) the large one even in a worker thread, the UI freezes for maybe 1 second.

Here is my query statement:

```
SELECT verse
FROM Translations
WHERE translatorId = ?
AND chapterNbr = ?
AND verseNbr BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY chapterNbr , verseNbr
```

The problem here is even if I deliberately query for just 1 row (1 result), the the UI still freezes.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Here's my very long code:

```
static void setVerseAdapter(final int[][] refs) {

    surahThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {         
                Cursor cursor = Translations.getTranslators();
                final int[] translationIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    translationIds[cursor.getPosition()] = cursor.getInt(0);
                }

               adapterVerses = new AdapterVerses
                        (context, getVersesArray(refs), Translations.getTranslationsArray(translationIds, refs)); // this one is the problem, the getTranslationsArray              

            // remaining code in this method is irrelevant ...
    });

    surahThread.start();
}

static Cursor[][] getTranslationsArray(int[] translationIds, int[]... refs) {

    if (!Settings.showTranslation)
        return new Cursor[][]{{}};

    Cursor[][] translations = new Cursor[refs.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < refs.length; i++) {
        int start = refs[i][0];
        int end = refs[i][1];
        int surahNbr = refs[i][2];
        translations[i] = getTranslations(translationIds, start, end, surahNbr);
    }

    return translations;
}


static Cursor[] getTranslations(int[] translatorIds, int start, int end, int surahNbr) {

    Cursor[] translations = new Cursor[translatorIds.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < translatorIds.length; i++) {
        translations[i] = readTrans(
                "SELECT verse " +
                        "FROM Translations " +
                        "WHERE translatorId = ? " +
                        "AND surahNbr = ? " +
                        "AND verseNbr BETWEEN ? AND ? " +
                        "ORDER BY surahNbr, verseNbr",
                translatorIds[i], surahNbr + 1, start, end
        );
    }

    return translations;
}

static Cursor readTrans(String query, Object... args) {
    SQLiteDatabase transDb = transExists ? DB.trans.db : DB.user.db; // using user.db results to no freezing
    return transDb.rawQuery(replaceArgs(query, args), null);
}
```

***Everything above works fine when I'm using DB.user.db instead of DB.trans.db.*** The difference between them is their size. First one is just ~**4MB** and the second (the problematic one) is about **65MB** when unpacked.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the code where you are querying the database and the code where you are using the `Cursor` that you get back from the query.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is... baffling. You are also making lots of queries in rapid succession, and that's going to result in poor performance in general. Specifically with regards to threading, make sure you do something with *every* `Cursor` you get back from the database *while you are on the background thread*. Methods like `query()` and `rawQuery()` do not actually do the queries. They set up `Cursors`, but the queries are not done until you actually do something with the `Cursor` (lazy evaluation). Call `getCount()`, if nothing else.

Comment: Did you measure times? I bet the problem is the adapter itself... I bet that you use one of the stupid solution for scrollable inside scrollable which avoids proper view reusing inside listview

Comment: My last edit ... [Everything above works fine when I'm using DB.user.db instead of DB.trans.db. The difference between them is their size. First one is just ~4MB and the second (the problematic one) is about 65MB when unpacked.] ... Can you think of another solution other than completely refactoring my code? Maybe regarding the statement above? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys but I solved my problem by simply creating an index of the table.

Comment: index all the fields which are used in JOIN links and in WHERE conditions.

Comment: @CommonsWare After 2 months in posting this question (and 6 months in Android development), I've run to the same problem and I've reread this post and I just realize how correct your comment is. I'm now calling some method (e.g. getCount) of the cursor in the background and the freeze is gone. But could you elaborate a little bit why is this the case? It's amazing that I haven't read this anywhere in the internet/documentary but only from you. Thank you very much for sharing your expertise.

Comment: @SidGo: Well, it is pretty much what I said. `query()`/`rawQuery()` return a `SQLiteCursor`. Initially, that object contains the query and a reference to the `SQLiteDatabase` to use for the query, but it does *not* contain the query results. The query is only executed if some method is called on the `Cursor` for which the results are needed, such as `getCount()` to return the # of rows in the result set. This is called "lazy evaluation", which is a common programming technique. It's just not well implemented here and is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IntentService** to run the queries far from the activity, then send back the result of the queries via **intent.putExtra** to the activity..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply indexing the offending table (yes, I didn't index it because I'm a total noob). Querying took ~600 ms for non-indexed and just 5 ms for indexed.

(The curious part that I still can't grasp is why does it freeze my UI to begin with? Isn't querying supposed to be done in the background thread I just created?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are waiting for the data to be queried. It does not matter whether you are moving the database operations into another thread; while the UI thread waits for the other thread to finish, it still blocks.

You should query only the data that you actually need to display, and ensure that the database operations are properly optimized.
But if the queries are still too slow, the only way to avoid freezing the UI is to show the UI without the data.